# How to make a background with 2 gradients in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a white background on the top 30% and blue on the bottom 70%.

Now what I need is the bottom part to have a gradient aswell.

I am using the following line for the white/blue part :

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, white 30%, #030A69 30%, #01063e);
```

I have a Jsfiddle of the current effect : https://jsfiddle.net/7j06431k/1/

And this is the desired effect:

[image: This is the desired effect]

How do i achieve this?

Comment: `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, white 30%, #030A69 30%, #010431);`

Comment: when you use percentage, you can't use direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following css:

```
background: linear-gradient(white 30%, #030A69 30%, #01063e);
```

```css
#mainColumn {
  background: linear-gradient(white 30%, #030A69 30%, #01063e);
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  border:2px solid magenta;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainColumn">
  
</div>
```